# Does $templateCache support images preloading?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to represent an image in time when it's needed without a spinner once controller is initialized. 
I've found that Angular can cache templates by using **$templateCache**. 
Can I use it in order to preload images when template has `<img>` tags and another question can it be used for DOM elements which were styled by CSS e.g.:

```
<div style="background-image:url(name.jpg)"></div>
```

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you render it directly through Angular, then, no. Angular only uses `$templateCache` for directive templates by default. If you wanted to do that you'd need to write your own directive that would look at `$templateCache` for those assets. That would involve writing your own `img` directly.

As for CSS, that's a definite no unless you parsed the CSS at runtime with Angular.

Angular does not intercept HTTP calls from outside of its framework.